# My exact search queries on github not working even though that query is present in one repository

Tags: github

I am searching in Github for:

```
const { firstElementChild: element } = target;
```

which is present in atleast this repository:
https://github.com/rspieker/jest-transform-svelte/blob/master/example/test/Sample.spec.js

It should ideally return atleast this result but it is returning empty:
https://github.com/search?q="const+%7B+firstElementChild%3A+element+%7D+%3D+target"&type=Code

Any idea why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Your file is the first answer of the query:

```
"const" "firstElementChild: element" "target"
```

https://github.com/search?q=%22const%22+%22firstElementChild%3A+element%22+%22target%22&type=Code

By avoiding `{ }` and `=`, the search succeeds.